# Windows Batch: How remove all blank (or empty) lines

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, sed

I am trying to remove all blank lines from a text file using a Windows batch program.

I know the simplest way do achieving this is ba**sh** is via regular expressions and the sed command:

```
sed -i "/^$/d" test.txt
```

**Question: Does Windows batch have an similar *simple* method for removing all lines from a text file? Otherwise, what is the *simplest* method to achieving this?**

**Note:**  I'm running this batch script to setup new Windows computers for customers to use, and so preferably no additional programs need to be installed (and then unistalled) to achieve this - ideally, I'll just be using the "standard" batch library.

Comment: this work for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/37298787/8747573

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For /f does not process empty lines:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("test.txt") do (echo(%%a)>>~.txt
move /y  ~.txt "test.txt"
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: "%%a was unexpected at this time." Any ideas? Also please can you explain what each word means in your answer (or point me to any doc that would help). Thanks!

Comment: @andyandy, You are trying this in command prompt directly, true? if so, state `%a` instead of `%%a`...

Comment: @aschipfl Many thanks! Yes I was trying it in command prompt directly - works now. Can you explain what the **"usebackq tokens=* delims="** means please (I think I understand everything else)?

Comment: @andyandy, type `for /?` in a command prompt window and read the help text; basically, `delims=` causes `for /F` to read each line as a whole, `tokens=*` is actually not needed here (but does no harm); `usebackq` allows the given file name `test.txt` to be placed within `""` (without `usebackq`, `test.txt` would be treated as literal string rather than a file path/name); `usebackq` and `""` are not needed here, but it is a good idea to use it though, because this way it works even with a file path/name containing spaces...

Comment: Althought it works fine for regular files, after processing a large file, the long lines are missing (> 62k characters). Be careful.

Answer (score 8):

You could also use FINDSTR:

```
findstr /v "^$" C:\text_with_blank_lines.txt > C:\text_without_blank_lines.txt
```

/V -- Print only lines that do NOT contain a match.
^ --- Line position: beginning of line
$ --- Line position: end of line

I usually pipe command output to it:

```
dir | findstr /v "^$"
```

If you have multiple words you're attempting to exclude, put the '^$' word first.

Test with this: 
`dir *.txt | findstr /v "^$ free bytes Directory Serial Windows"`

This option won't remove all blank lines, despite '^$' being included. 
`dir *.txt | findstr /v "free bytes Directory Serial Windows ^$"`

You also might find these answers to a similar question helpful, since some 'blank lines' may include spaces or tabs.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45021815/5651418
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16062125/5651418

Comment: much safer and faster than the `for` approach. Btw: also: `dir|findstr .`. The `.` is `findstr`'s wildcard for "any char" (so it finds each line that contains at least one char (besides the line ending)