# JMeter tries to use EOF in request

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing

I have a HTTP request in a thread group that reads from a single column csv file to get values to populate a parameter in the request URL.

Below is my configuration for these:
[image: thread group]
[image: http request]
[image: csv data]

There are 30 values in the csv data file.

My goal is to have each thread start at the beginning of the file once it gets to the end, effectively infinitely looping through the data values until the scheduler duration expires.
However, what actually happens is some requests try and use  (see screenshot below) and therefore fail.
[image: failing requests]

I have tried [this](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) but that just stops at the 30th iteration i.e. the end of the csv data file.

I assume I have some config option(s) wrong but I can't find anything online to suggest what they might be. Can anyone point me in the right direction (what i should be searching for?) or provide a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably it's test data issue, double check your CSV file and **make sure it doesn't contain empty lines**, if they are - [remove them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34922836/2897748) and your test should start working as expected.

For small files with only one column you can use [__StringFromFile() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) - it's much easier to set up and use.